# How to create a container component to use it multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react component I want to fill **inside of another component**. I want to be able to use this `smooth scroll` component kind of as a container, that way I could use it inside of several different components and easily enclose them with the `smooth scroll component`'s html, css and js.

Smooth scroll component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="smooth-scroll-viewport">
            <div className="smooth-scroll-container">

             NEW COMPONENT'S CONTENT

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

How I want to use it inside of another component:

```
<SmoothScroll>
   <div className="some-content">
      test
   </div>
</SmoothScroll>
```

How can I realize such behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `children` props from React

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="smooth-scroll-viewport">
            <div className="smooth-scroll-container">
              {this.props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Now you will be able to use like

```
<SmoothScroll>
   <div className="some-content">
      test
   </div>
</SmoothScroll>
```

Comment: + See https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html for documentation